# hook_taxonomy_term_update(), where does it get invoked in drupal's core code?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I looked after a `module_invoke_all('taxonomy_term_update')` in the taxonomy module (and more in the entire Drupal core) but I didn't find anything.

Where does that hook get invoked in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's invoked from [`taxonomy_term_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7).

The reason you can't find it is because the hook gets invoked via an interpolated string, depending on the current operation (insert or update):

```
module_invoke_all("taxonomy_term_$op", $term);
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Even while searching for `invoke` in the code I saw nothing... I need new glasses!